# CSS3 how to make animation go in a loop and never stop?

Tags: css

I have a red square moving left and right. And then it stops, how do i make it that it goes on till i leave the web page?

Comment: [this link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) seems to have the answer (not sure though, they're talking about a slider..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the property `infinite`

For example

```
-webkit-animation: NAME-OF-ANIMATION 10s linear infinite;
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/Ch7wd/)

Comment: @jacktheripper - Looks like he's not happy yet. So, I gave you +1 instead! ;) :P